# How do I align the dropdown arrow on a HTML5 date input to the right side?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

It goes without saying I am new to HTML and Bootstrap.

I have this HTML:

```
<dd class="col-4">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="dateaddon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="date" name="resDate" class="form-control input-sm" aria-describedby="dateaddon" placeholder=".input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                        <dd class="col-4">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="dateaddon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="time" name="resDate" class="form-control input-sm" aria-describedby="dateaddon" placeholder=".input-sm">
                            </div>
                        </dd>
```

Which gives me an an output like this (note how tall the date/time inputs are and that the dropdown arrow/clear button are shown at the bottom instead of the to the right of the date):

[image]

My question is how do I get the date input to be smaller and with the dropdown arrow/clear button aligned to the right of the input? I don't want the input boxes to be that tall.

I can manually change the height using CSS, but this does not give the desired result; it just hides dropdown, etc and makes the input unusable.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Znaneswar, I did that: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/22t0ubb1/#&togetherjs=jSfMI5kTPI). Of course, the formatting looks correct in the JSFiddle. Maybe because some of the CDNs I added to it were different versions than what I am using in my project?

Comment: Yeah, in fiddle place exact cdns what you are using.

Comment: OK, I noticed that when I use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css in my JSFiddle, the formatting is correct. However, when I use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css (which is what I am using in my project) it is not correct. Could this be an issue with alpha.6? Please check out my JSFiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/22t0ubb1/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6. When I use Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta, it works just fine.